# Radio button and saving the state values in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I need to create two radio buttons and I want to store there state values (enabled or disabled) in an array. can anybody share the code?

Comment: The component offered by iOS is the UISwitch instead of a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

take a mutable dictionary in header file

```
NSMutableDicionary *dictionaryForRadioStates;
```

and in implementation

ANd in implementation file on tap of radio button

```
 [dictionaryForRadioStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:radioButton.enabled] forKey:@"radioButton1"];


[dictionaryForRadioStates setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:radioButton.enabled] forKey:@"radioButton2"];
```

You can get values back like this

```
BOOL state = [[dictionaryForRadioStates valueForKey:@"radioButton1"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete code for using the Radio Button : (You need to use the custom button to perform this task)

**In .h file:**

```
//Option Menu Buttons
IBOutlet UIButton *option1;
IBOutlet UIButton *option2;

 -(IBAction)MyCustomRadioButtons:(id)sender; // Give connection to this method through Xib/code .
```

**.m file**

```
-(IBAction)MyCustomRadioButtons:(id)sender
{
    if(sender==option1)
    {
        if([option1 isSelected]==TRUE)
        {
            [option1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            option1.selected=FALSE;

            [option2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            option2.selected=TRUE;

        }
        else {

            [option1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            option1.selected=TRUE;

            [option2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            option2.selected=FALSE;
        }

    }

    if(sender==option2)
    {
        if([option2 isSelected]==TRUE)
        {
            [option2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            option2.selected=FALSE;

            [option1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            option1.selected=TRUE;

        }
        else {

            [option2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            option2.selected=TRUE;
            [self ShowActionSheetWithPicker:sender];
            [option1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            option1.selected=FALSE;


        }
    }
}
```

Below are the images to use :

[image]

[image]

AS far as storing is concerned, you can use the Dictionary to store the values through key Values.

Hope that would help to do it with coding.

Comment: This is not help..... but please make sure you should help other guys over this blog by answering & gaining the points. You can improve your profile by accepting the answers & by vote up too.